# C++ - When to use pointers to class data members?

Tags: c++

I've been coding in C++ and I was wondering if someone could help me with the general reason why we sometimes need to make pointers to class members and other times we don't.

For example if we are coding a Binary Tree

I implement it as

```
class BinaryTree{

    BinaryTree * left;
    BinaryTree * right;
    int val;

    public:
        BinaryTree(int v) {left = NULL; right = NULL; val = v;}
        //implementation of any other neccessary functions
};
```

I use the BinaryTree pointers to left and right, because we can't do it without the pointer since BinaryTree does not exist at that point in time.

Are there any other reasons to do this? Is there anyway around this?

Also, if we put pointer member functions, will the implicit destructor handle the deletion of them?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If your class owns the pointer it is holding, it means it owns the memory the pointer points to, and so your class will need to clean up that memory. If you are not using a smart pointer or `std::optional`, then this means you need to follow the rule of three.

Comment: Is there anyway to create a BinaryTree class similar to mine without the use of pointers?

Comment: You can use `std::optional` instead of a straight-up pointer, and then you would get deep copy semantics. Deep copy semantics are usually more desirable for containers such as trees.

Comment: What you need is `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @jxh deep copy can also be achieved  easily by implementing a custom copy constructor and sometimes it might be desirable to share a specific subtree among multiple trees for performance reasons.

Comment: @Paranaix: Implementing a custom copy constructor would probably defeat the relevance of using a smart pointer.

Comment: @milleniumbug: That would work, but then there is no copy. As I had already stated, any smart pointer will work, but `std::optional` gives deep copy semantics, which is what most people expect out of a container (e.g., `std::vector`).

Comment: @jxh `std::optional` cannot be used here, as it stores the object directly (that is, not on heap), and obviously can't be used with incomplete types.

Comment: The best solution is to create your own smart pointer, that's almost like `std::unique_ptr`, but also defines a copy constructor and copy assignment operator - that's very simple to define.

Comment: @milleniumbug: Silly. Then, I would use `std::list` as my smart pointer replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a box:

[image: A box, representing a struct here]

it has a volume of about one cubic meter, so it can only store objects that have total volume of one cubic meter. And **it definitely can't store** two identical boxes as itself. Note that each one of these two boxes would also need to contain two boxes like it, and so on, and so on.

This is a `struct`:

```
struct BinaryTree {
    BinaryTree left;
    BinaryTree right;
    int val;
};
```

it has a finite size equal to `sizeof(BinaryTree)`, so it can only store objects that have total size less or equal to `sizeof(BinaryTree)`. And **it definitely can't store** two values of type `BinaryTree`. Note that each one of these two values would also need to store two values like it, and so on, and so on.

Since the struct instances can't contain other instances of the same struct, and we need to define relations between them, and trees are definitely hierarchical, we use pointers here.

Note that the only thing that so called raw pointer to T (that is, `T*`) does, is to point to `T`. Since pointing is the only task of such pointer, **destruction won't destroy the pointed object, only the pointer**.

There exist types that behave like pointers, but also do other tasks, like managing lifetime of pointed object. These are C++11's `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::shared_ptr`, and many others. I highly recommend using them.

Comment: In my case I thought I was going to spend less memory space by not storing `ASTNode` pointers inside `AssignmentExpression`. I think I'm not very used to C or C++... very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Objects often hold members that only need to be created based on run time conditions or parameters. You want to delay creation as late as possible. This is a common case for using pointers.